# Some Parts Of A Mesh Not Moving With Generated Rig

Tags: rigging

I used Rigify to generate a rig, but some parts of the mesh are not moving or rotating at all.

Does Anyone Know Why?

[image]

In this picture I moved a part of the rig (the green lines),  which I believe is supposed to control the shoulders of the mesh, but the mesh didn't move at all.

Comment: In rigify the green controls are FK controls and the red ones are IK. if you press 'N' to open the rigify control side panel you can toggle between them using the FK>IK switches . I suggest you watch [this YT video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vKgH5zXIYmM) from CGDIVE which explains how to use them.

Comment: Ok , thanks a lot John!

Comment: No problem. In this case it was easier to post a tutorial link which explained it thoroughly rather than put it all in an answer.